# How to move multiple lines code together left or rights in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I want to select multiple lines and move them together (left/right/up/down). How to do that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Moving lines left or right, i.e. changing the level of indentation, can be done in almost all code editors using <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Moving blocks of code up and down can be done in Eclipse using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>.

See *Preferences -> General -> Keys*.

Comment: I used to use Ctrl + [ and Ctrl + ] on VS Code for the same purpose, but seems like they stopped working on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

you can use '***tab***' or '***shift+tab***' to move your code lines to right but it does not work when you want to move them to left, at least not in my python script.